# Scopes captured by an EventListener include all let variables but not var variables?

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

I have the following code for attaching an event listener to a html element. I understand that the callback for this event listener forms a closure with its lexical environment.

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var x = 0;

function attachEventListener(element, x){
    let count = 0;
    let el = document.getElementById("counter");
    element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        count++;
        el.innerHTML = count + ` ${x}`;
    });
}
```

My question is the difference between the capture of var and let variables through a Script scope.
As seen in the two images below, if I define `submit` and `x` as `var` then they do not get captured via a Script scope. But when defined as `let` variables then they do get captured via a Script scope.
My main question is why does the `Script` Scope get created with the event listener like this?

[image: var elements do not get captured via a script scope.]
[image: let elements get captured via a script scope.]

I tried to declare the variables in the two ways and thought the behaviour for the two would be same in terms of Scope captured by the event listener. I know let variables are block scoped and var are global or local scoped. But did not expect the difference in Script scopes.

Comment: You're comparing apples with oranges here. In the first image, you've expanded the "Closure (attachEventListener)" scope, in the second image, you've expanded the "Script" scope. Of course they're different!

Answer (score 0):

Top-level `var` variables are defined as properties of the global object, in a browser that would be `window`. So no a script scope for them. Though you can isolate `var` in a module like `const/let`.

On the other hand `const/let` top-level variables are defined in script/module scope.

Because of this and other features of `var` I consider `var` as legacy, outdated, dangerous and Heisenbuggy. When I come to a team the first thing I prohibit `var` with ESLint.

```js
var test = 'var';

console.log(window.test);

const test2 = 'const';

console.log(window.test2);
```

```html
<script type="module">
  
  var moduleVar = 'module var';
  console.log(window.moduleVar);

</script>
```

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by "script scope". Top-level lexical declarations are not scoped to a single script.

Comment: @Bergi i agree, just difficult to formulate, that's rather a script level than a script scope

Comment: Call it the "global lexical scope" maybe?